# Custom taskbar icon in tkinter and customtkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

How can I get a custom **taskbar** icon in `tkinter` and `customtkinter`?

I tried:

```
# Importing customtkinter as ctk
import customtkinter as ctk

# Creating the root window
root = ctk.CTk()

# Creating the root's title
root.title('test')

# Setting window icon
root.iconbitmap('C\MyDirecory\MyFolder\favicon.ico')

# How can I set the taskbar icon?
```

I tried all the suggestions [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) gave me, but none worked.

Comment: Re *"`C\MyDirecory\MyFolder\favicon.ico`"*: Is that notation for a file path on Windows supposed to work? Not *"`C:\MyDirecory\MyFolder\favicon.ico`"* (colon, C:) or *"`/C/MyDirecory/MyFolder/favicon.ico`"* (like [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway))?

Comment: cont' - The latter with an ***absolute*** path (leading '`/`').

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not an option.
If you want a taskbar icon, you'll have to export your .py file to an .exe with the icon you want.  Then it will appear with the right icon on your taskbar.

Comment: Thanks, I exported to .exe using pyintsaller using the argument -i favicon.png

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix:

```
root.iconbitmap('C:\MyDirecory\MyFolder\\favicon.ico')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: currently should be `root.iconbitmap('C:\\MyDirecory\\MyFolder\\favicon.ico')`